# Is android Region is always a rectangular area or it may be polygonal or curvy?

Tags: android, graphics, region

Does Android Region ([android.graphics.Region](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Region.html)) always have a rectangular area or can it be polygonal or rounded (curvy)?

Actually I have to do some `Region.Op.UNION` and `Region.Op.INTERSECTION` operation with multiple regions.
I want to know the shape of Ultimate Output Region, does it still have a rectangular area or not?

Comment: I would assume not due to the `public boolean isRect()` method being a little redundant if it was always a rectangle. There seem to be a number of operations in the docs referring to Paths which can contain arcs etc.

Answer (score 1):

It can be complex (`isComplex()`), i.e. it consists of more than one rectangle. Not sure what do you mean by "curvy", but it can be polygonal. If I understand it correctly, you can use `getBoundaryPath()` to get the Path describing resulting shape.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the documentation would lead one to conclude that a Region can be anything *but* a rectangle, it being constructed from either a rectangle, an x,y coordinate plus width and height, or by another region.

One can describe a rectangle from a path, so getBoundaryPath() does not necessarily conclude that a non-rectangle is possible. An encompassing rectangular boundary may instead be implied.

The isComplex() property only says that it consists of multiple rectangles. Are they all bound by a single exterior, defining rectangle? If so, how do we separate them? In the absence of sufficient documentation, one cannot tell without experimentation:

The following code describes a path and creates a polygonal region. We start with an array of any number of coordinate pairs. Then:

```
    //describe a path corresponding to the transformed polygon
    Path transformPath;
    transformPath = new Path();

    //starting point
    transformPath.moveTo(getTransformedPolygon()[0], getTransformedPolygon()[1]);

    //draw a line from one point to the next
    for(int i = 2; i < arrayCoordinates.length; i = i + 2)
    {
        transformPath.lineTo(arrayCoordinates[i], arrayCoordinates[i + 1]);
    }

    //then end at the starting point to close the polygon
    transformPath.lineTo(arrayCoordinates[0], arrayCoordinates[1]);

    //describe a region (clip area) corresponding to the game area (my example is a game app)
    Region clip = new Region(0, 0, gameSurfaceWidth, gameSurfaceHeight);

    //describe a region corresponding to the transformed polygon path
    transformRegion = new Region();
    transformRegion.setPath(transformPath, clip);
```

If you display the region as a string, you will see the several pair of coordinates that make up the polygonal shape.